# Center the coordinate system of python pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I would like to create images using mathematical equations / functions and python pillow. For example,

pseudo code:

```
iterate through pixels
if x^2 + y^2 <= 25, pixel_color = green.
Draws a solid circle of radius 5
```

I am aware python pillow has inbuilt functions to draw circles. I would like to draw other complicated functions as well.

The problem is that (0,0) of a pillow image is at the top left corner.
Can I somehow center the coordinate system of python pillow so that I can draw the whole circle instead of a quadrant?

I am again aware that I can use (x-x1)<sup>2</sup> + (y-y1)<sup>2</sup> <= 25 to center the circle at (x1, y1), but it would be very convenient if I can center the axes like in case of `nannou`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am unaware of such an option in PIL, and wrote my own wrapper in my hobby project: https://codeberg.org/erwinrossen/vangogh/src/branch/main/src/common/canvas.py

Comment: @physicalattraction That's helpful and yours is an interesting project. Thanks for the code and the comment.